# How to get last offset in jira active object pagination?

Tags: jira, jira-plugin

```
public List<Forest> getForest(int limit, int offset) {
    try {
        return newArrayList(ao.find(Forest.class, Query.select().order("ID DESC").limit(limit).offset(offset)));
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

The above code working fine, but its not return total number of rows.
So i unable to apply last page index.
I have applied First, Next & Previous

Answer (score 2):

I guess you need to "count" your records:

```
Query query = Query.select().order("ID DESC");
int count = ao.count(Forest.class, query);
```